# The quickest US President to drop a bomb or invade as stated

Tags: united-states, president, military, campaigning

## Two Correlated Questions

1. Which US elected Presidents stated during their election campaign that they'd bomb, invade, or take a strong military action against a US foreign adversary and actually do it?
2. Who of them have been the quickest in terms of time between being sworn in office on inauguration day, and actually taking any correlated physical action?

### Why do I ask, well because...

On Donald Trump's **campaign trail** he talked about [***bombing shit out of ISIS***](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aWejiXvd-P8) and about all the oil fields they control and so forth in the **Middle East** region, and then he actually dropped a bomb.

- So, Trump was elected into office on ***January 20th 2017*** and the bomb was dropped on the adversary group on ***April 13th 2017***, so that's ***83 days*** for Trump's record.

#### Event Supporting Items

- [US drops largest non-nuclear bomb in Afghanistan](http://www.cnn.com/2017/04/13/politics/afghanistan-isis-moab-bomb/)

  > "The US military dropped America's most powerful non-nuclear bomb on
  > ISIS targets in Afghanistan Thursday, the first time this type of
  > weapon has been used in battle, according to US officials."
- [Trump calls Afghanistan bombing a ‘very successful mission’](http://www.cnbc.com/2017/04/13/trump-calls-afghanistan-operation-a-very-successful-mission.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going back to the previous president:

Prior to taking office [Obama promised to send 10,000 more troops into Afghanistan](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2008/jul/15/barackobama.usa1).

By 2010 it appears that [they had added over 60,000 troops.](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/statements/2010/may/30/colin-powell/obama-has-increased-troops-afghanistan/)

Obama had also [promised to kill Osama Bin Laden in 2008](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/article/2011/may/01/obama-vowed-kill-osama-bin-laden/). [The US killed him in 2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osama_bin_Laden#Death).